# You must use the "set" method to update an entry during insert

Tags: php, reactjs, codeigniter-3

I use codeigniter 3, I want to insert a post data to database, but the error is `You must use the "set()"` method to update an entry. I can register user using "$this->db->insert($this->table, $data); ". but not via why Post page?

view: create.jsx

```
try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:80/test/index.php/post/create", newPost);
      // window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

post.php

```
public function create()
    {
        $input_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data_arr = json_decode($input_data, true);

        unset($data_arr['file']);
        if ($this->post_model->insert_data($data_arr) == 0) {
            echo 'fail';
            return;
        }
        echo 'success';

    }
```

MY_Model.php

```
function insert_data($data)
    {   
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data); 
        return $this->db->affected_rows(); 
    }
```

I tried to rebuild phpmyadmin post table but nothing happened and tried to print out table name, which is post and  that data is array.

Comment: Can you please specify the filename on top of each code block as well?

Comment: @Adi ok! thanks

Comment: more detail:
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: core/MY_Model.php

Line Number: 28
28:$this->db->insert($this->table, $data);